# Watir Webdriver +Chromedriver: ADFS Authentication

Tags: google-chrome, automation, watir, adfs

I'm attempting to load a page that does a call to ADFS for authentication purposes. On the page load, there is a redirect and then popup to enter credentials.

- HTTPS must be used.
- Chrome must be used as the testing browser.

So, when loading the page everything is working fine, but I'm forced to manually enter credentials when running the test. After inputting the credentials everything is fine, but is there a way to leverage Watir to input this for me? I've tried popping the username:password into the link already with no success, and since I really need to use Chrome the Firefox plugins are moot.

---

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto 'https://internalUAT.clientwebsite.com/'
b.link(:text => 'HR Dashboard').click
```

---

I'm not allowed to post images due to reputation constraints, but please visit

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUZ8Z.png

for a screenshot.

Comment: Alternatively, the focus is on the username field when the page is loaded... Is there a way to have it input a string of text without selecting a specific element? That way I could just have it enter the Username, then tab, then enter the Password, then enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try passing credentials with the `https://user:pass@foo.com` technique, do you have any unusual characters in the username or password? (Maybe you have a `DOMAIN\username` domain prefix?)

If so you might want to make sure any such characters in the credential string are properly escaped.

If that's not the problem, and there's no other way to disable the auth prompt for your tests, then your best bet (IMO) is to write a separate script (or thread) that uses RAutomation (or some other UI automation library of your choosing) to enter your credentials and click the Log In button.

See https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation

The test cases in the following file contain examples of using RAutomation's send_keys method, which could prove useful:

https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/blob/master/spec/window_spec.rb

For the record, it looks like RAutomation may have been used by watir-classic for dialog handling:

https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/master/lib/watir-classic/modal_dialog.rb

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/ModalDialog